# TestCafe - How to get the html output of an element on fail

Tags: html, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

When I run tests I cannot capture screenshots at the moment in Jenkins without some heavy work. What I would like to do is get the HTML output of the body to see what is displayed when a particular error occurs.

What I've already tried is getting the textContent, which is pretty close but I would like to get the stringified HTML if possible.

```
await t
    .click(something)
    .wait(1000)
    .click(somethingElse)
    .wait(1000)
    .expect(mySelector.exists)
    .ok(await Selector('body').textContent, { timeout: 25000 }); // if .ok fails it should print out the contents of body
```

I get the text but would want HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [Selector Custom Properties](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402829/guides/basic-guides/select-page-elements#extend-selectors-with-custom-properties-and-methods). There is an example of how to get innerHTML of the element.